# How can I get command arguments with D-trace on OSX

Tags: macos, dtrace

I'm trying to preview run commands with the args with D-trace. I tried something like this:

```
sudo dtrace -n 'syscall::execve:return {printf("%s\n", curpsinfo->pr_psargs);}'
```

But on OSX this code returns only commands names not their args.

I find [this](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/1980539?start=0&tstart=0) forum thread but code in last answer doesn't works for me.

Answer (score 5):

with a little help of my colleague we manage to fix script mentioned in question. [This](https://gist.github.com/1242279) is correct one. The problem was that forum markup removed some `*` and `_` chars.